# Google maps slow from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, maps

I am reading mysql tables and generating an xml file:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

To generate the map, I generate a JSON file.

My database contains several thousand records, this generates 5000+ lines of JSON.

The mysql query result is different depending on many settings, and needs to be accessible from multiple users at same time.

Each time the map is loaded, this json file is parsed, then the map loads in about 3-6 seconds (depend the client device).

Is there a way to speed up this process, or an alternative way to achieve the same result?

Any suggestion is welcome.

// Cédric

Answer (score 0):

I don't see enough detail to give any specific advice, but if I were in a situation like this my first question would be: Is it *absolutely necessary* to load up the entire 5K lines of JSON each time the map is loaded? What kind of data does the JSON contain that's being needed all at once? The whole point of AJAX is to load parts of resources only as they're resources (and Google Maps is a master at this); I'd look for some way to only load the highest-level or most-immediate data when the map first loads, then load in more as needed later on.

Comment: The JSON contains only minimal needed values for each marker like this sample : "id":"1234",","lat":52.19341979,"lng":-0.20524121,"rt":"Title","ic":"icon.png" I cannot make it more little. I think I do not need a specific to code advice (all work fine), but a new method to load the markers.

Comment: The data does look minimal per marker, but again: Do ALL 5K markers need to be loaded right when the map loads? Maybe they do. But that's the first place I would look.

Comment: What did you mean? Loading the makers depending on the current viewport ?

Comment: Perhaps. I'm speaking in very general terms because I'm not super familiar with the Google Maps API, but it's hard for me to believe that all 5K markers are shown to every user who loads the page. If the initial map viewport / container will only show, say, 250 of those markers, you only need to render those markers initially; then find some way to poll the map container and if it changes focus or zoom, then load the additional markers as needed (if Google allows you to add markers after-the-fact). This is way more complex, but could save a lot of loading time.